# Capture/upload from camera/gallery using ionic and ngCordova

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to create a sample application that will either take a picture from camera, or load an image from gallery on the screen.

Can someone help me for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$cordovaCamera`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) of `ngCordova` to take a photo and save it.

Register `ngCordova` as dependency in **app.js**:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])
```

**controller.js**:

```
.controller('PhotosCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
  /**
   * Add a photo.
   */
  $scope.addPhoto = function(){
    var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("Error while getting the image!", err)
    });
  };
});
```

**template.html**:

```
<ion-view view-title="Photos">
  <ion-content>
    <button type="button" class="button" ng-click="addPhoto()">Add photo</button>
    <img id="myImage" />
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```